# what is the best way to copy and replicate data

Tags: windows-server-2003, replication, robocopy

I have two HP Proliant DL160 G5s. One is currently in production (we'll call it NAS01) and the other (we'll call it NAS02) is built to the same config and almost ready to go.

What I will be doing is replicating data from 01 to 02 so we can use 02 as a failsafe and this is the one we will be running NetBackup on for tape backups.

I plan on using DFSr (both a re running Server 2003R2) to replicate the data. What I would like to know is what is the best way to do the initial copy (about 1 TB).

I was thinking I could use RoboCopy (or RichCopy) for the initial run then implement DFSr to replicate the data afterward. I would like to keep the same file permissions on 02 as 01 so in the even of a hardware failure of 01 I can remap the drives to 02 so the users can continue working.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, robocopy is probably the best way to do the initial copy.

Comment: Ok cool. I noticed on the robocopy page there's a link to RichCopy. It looks like RichCopy is basically a newer version of RoboCopy. Any thoughts on that? Cheers!

Comment: Kind of - RichCopy is essentially Robocopy with a better version of the Robocopy GUI (an add-on tool.) I don't see any advantages of RichCopy over Robocopy, as far as features go. It's multithreaded, but so is robocopy on the newest Windows OSes. I prefer a CLI tool anyway for stuff like this, because then you can incorporate it into your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure that it's not as powerful as robocopy, but Microsoft also produce a user-friendly tool called [SyncToy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SyncToy), which provides a nice simple GUI, and a few different options for synchronising folders ("Synchronise", "contribute", ...).  I've tried it at home syncing a folder on my PC with a network share, and it seems to work OK, even providing a "preview" facility.  But then, I was only syncing about 2Gb of files.